# Plug-in not firing few times in cordova-2.3.0 and iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an iphone application using cordova-2.3.0 and ios6. in that application i am using sherekit plugin. it is working fine in home page of application, when we move into next pages all the plugins are not firing most of the times. this is below code for calling sharekit plugin.

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "ShareKitPlugin", "share", ["Hi", "http://www.google.com"]);
```

thanks.

Comment: Could you describe with a bit more details what means: "when we move into next pages". Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your consideration. The problem was the events are loading before deviceready. now I am triggering those cordove.exce events after deviceReady so they are working fine now.